# an opposite function or code to preg_match_all

Tags: php

I have a built in PHP function that in this example I am using to turn the content inside a span tag into an array.

```
preg_match_all('/<span.*?<\/span>/', $var, $newVar);
```

is it possible to kind of place into an array the other text between the span tags.

```
<p>i am a sentence <span id="blah"> im content inside of the span </span> im another sentence <span id="anId">i m another span content</span> im the last sentence in this p tag <span id="last">im the third span tag in this p tag<span></p>
```

more specifically the above function will output the above p tag as an array of span tags with just the text inside and no tags around it which is good step one accomplished it would look something like this

```
array ([0] => im content inside of the span [1] => i m another span content [2] => im the third span tag in this p tag )
```

this is the text inside the span tags, I want to use these to implode the string.

now I want to do the opposite and have the strings in between them as an array.

I want to get an output of

```
array ([0] => i am a sentence [1] => im another sentence [2] => im the last sentence in this p tag )
```

this is the text outside of the span tags.
Surely this is possible?

Comment: Give an example of the result you want.

Comment: It sounds like you just need some parenthesis in the pattern.

Comment: After your edit: Try `preg_split`

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_split()`, using a regular expression that matches a tag as the delimiter.

```
$array = preg_split('/<[^>]*>/', $var);
```

Comment: This is good so far but what if i don't want the contents inside the span tag to but put into the array, this function puts both of the examples i've shown in one. how would i get the second example from this where the span content and tags are also the delimiter?

Comment: dont worry ive research and found out to do the whole span tag and the content inside would be $array = preg_split('/<.*>/', $var); https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnu4febXKx0

Comment: That won't work. Since `.*` is greedy, it will treat everything from the first `<` to the last `>` as one delimiter. That's why I have `[^>]*`.

Comment: here is another quesiotn that i think you might be able to help me with, i want the strpos of the values of the arrays inside the keys https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469757/preg-split-without-the-function.