# preg_split without the function

Tags: php

I would like to learn how to use a set of php code that does the same thing as the `preg_split` function, without using the actual `preg_split` function. using this as an example

```
<?php
$string = '<p>i am a sentence <span id="blah"> im content inside of the span </span> im another sentence <span id="anId">i m another span content</span> im the last sentence in this p tag <span id="last">im the third span tag in this p tag<span></p>';

if ( preg_match_all("/<span[^>]*>/", $string, $temporaryArray) ) {
    foreach ($temporaryArray as $values) {
        $theArrayWithoutUsingPregSplit[$strpos] = $values;
    }
}

?>
```

This doesnt work however because `preg_match_all` just counts how much times it matches without getting the actual string. but the person on this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php#118326 is able to do it. could someone help please.

additionally i would like to have the `strpos()` function to use as keys for each array element so that i can see the position of the values in the `$string` variable, in the example that i have given the variable has no value.

the end output im trying to get from the string variable is

```
array (
    [$thisVariableIsANumberWhichIsTheStrPosOfTheValue]  i am a sentence 
    [$thisVariableIsANumberWhichIsTheStrPosOfTheValue]  im content inside of the span 
    [$thisVariableIsANumberWhichIsTheStrPosOfTheValue]  im another sentence 
    [$thisVariableIsANumberWhichIsTheStrPosOfTheValue]  i m another span content 
    [$thisVariableIsANumberWhichIsTheStrPosOfTheValue]  im the last sentence in this p tag 
    [$thisVariableIsANumberWhichIsTheStrPosOfTheValue]  im the third span tag in this p tag 
)
```

The reason i dont think `preg_split` is the best thing to use in this scenario is because i cant have the array keys representing the `strpos` of the values.

sorry for so much writing, i try to make the question as understandable as i can make it or people might downvote it, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: So given your string, what do you want as output?

Comment: an array similar to usin the preg_split function but as the keys = the strpos of the value. array ( [$strpos] => $value [$strpos] => $value); or array( [0] array ([0] => $strpos] [1] => $value) [1] array ([0] => $strpos] [1] => $value) [2] array ([0] => $strpos] [1] => $value) );

Comment: Why do you think `preg_match_all` juset counts how many times it matches? The matches are all in `$temporaryArray`. This is a 2-dimensional array, the first element contains an array of all lthe whole matches, the other elements contain arrays of the capture groups.

Comment: if you create a page and use the code i have given this will be your output Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) ), with this i can see how many matches it has found but not the actual content of the array that it should have taken from the string.

Answer (score 0):

With DOMDocument:

```
$string = '<p>i am a sentence <span id="blah"> im content inside of the span </span> im another sentence <span id="anId">i m another span content</span> im the last sentence in this p tag <span id="last">im the third span tag in this p tag<span></p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xp->query('//text()') as $textNode) {
    echo trim($textNode->nodeValue), PHP_EOL;
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/PB7pe)

This approach consists to ask after each text node using the XPath query language with the simple query `//text()` (text node anywhere in the DOM tree).

Comment: this is good so far but it doesnt output the strpos of the array values

Comment: @JevonMcPherson: and for what reason do you want to keep the string positions? (note also that the best you can do with DOMDocument is to get the line number).

Comment: I want to put some of the texts in span tags with an id of the strpos so that a person can navigate to whichever paragraph he or she pleases, the sting could be a long string if its user generated.

Comment: @JevonMcPherson: I think you have an XY problem (in short your are looking for a solution to solve a problem, but your problem is here only because you are going the wrong way to do what you want). If I were you, I will explain what you are trying to do (what is your main goal). You can edit your question or perhaps a new post.

Comment: What got me here asking the question is me using the preg split function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348871/an-opposite-function-or-code-to-preg-match-all/48349606?noredirect=1#comment83736375_48349606 , but i was unable to get the strpos for the values of the array, i just want an array that comes from a string that also has the positions (strpos) of the different values it has recieved from the string.

Comment: @JevonMcPherson: You don't understand. For what reason, for what goal do you want to do that?

Comment: so that a person can navigate to whichever paragraph he or she please imagine a website like wikipedia that has lots of text and subtitles, its usefull to have a link or a navbar that can navigate to whichever paragraph subtitle the user pleases. i want to use the str pos as the id e.g id='paragraph117' so that i can use a link or navbar to navigate to whichever paragraph.

Comment: @JevonMcPherson: arghh! In other words, you ask that to add link/anchors to a web page? It's absolutely not the way to do that. Please take the time to read a tutorial about DOMDocument (it's the way to edit XML/HTML code), in short DOMDocument is a like a tree for your html and has methods to edit it all the way you want (adding attributes, requesting specific nodes with XPath...). It isn't so simple to learn but It's clearly the way to go.

Comment: I apologise if you found this question stressfull.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text between the `<span>` and `</span>` you need to change your regexp to match both of them, and use a capture group in between.

`$temporaryArray` is a 2-dimensional array; element `0` contains the matches for the whole regexp, element `N` contains the matches for the Nth capture group. So the strings you want are in `$temporaryArray[1]`. If you also want the positions, use the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` option. With this option, each match is an array `[ "string", strpos ]`.

```
if ( preg_match_all('#<span[^>]*>(.*?)</span>#', $string, $temporaryArray, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) ) {
    $theArrayWithoutUsingPregSplit = array();
    foreach($temporaryArray[1] as $match) {
        $theArrayWithoutUsingPregSplit[$match[1]] = $match[0];
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/bOTNLo)

Comment: could you show me an example please like on this website https://3v4l.org/5gVut or whichever website you prefer because when i try to use this code on my laptop it outputs the array of strpos but the parts for the text is empty and this website give no output.

Comment: Also could PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE be used for the preg_split function?

Comment: I don't know offhand, what does the documentation say?

Comment: Your regexp only matches the `<span>` tags, not the text between them. Why do you think this is a way to implement `preg_split`?

Comment: I'm not able to get your desired output, though. The regexp only matches `<span>` elements, not other elements. Also, you have mismatched tags, the last `<span>` should be `</span>`.

Comment: i just wanted an array for the string that also has the strpos of the values, i thought preg_split was unable to do it so i thought i needed to do the function manually. i dont mind which way you show me for the desired output as long as it works. your answer seemed good, it gave me the strpos it just wasnt giving me the values, for me they were empty looking like this [0] => .

Comment: Regular expressions are just a horrible tool for trying to parse HTML.

Comment: Do you have a better solution to get the desired output for the string, asking a question and then answering your own question would be very usefull, even an example without html tags would be usefull too.

Comment: No, I don't. I think you'll need to write your own loop that uses `preg_match()` with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` option, as well as the `offset` argument to start from the middle.

Answer (score 0):

im so sorry for the trouble i might have caused you, the reason i wanted to do it without the preg_split() function is because i thought that preg_split() couldnt return the strpos of the strings it returns but all this time it was simply something like this 
`$Array = preg_split('/<[^>]*>/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);` 
to get what i wanted. i just want to be able to uget the strpos and aswell as the strings from a string. i love how this website has such a helpfull community and i thank you all for your help, i greatly appreciate it.